# Application ends before displaying final output

Tags: c++, visual-c++-2010

I am doing a console application for training.
When I debug the code below, it closes itself before displaying

```
 std::cout << e <<  std::endl;
```

If I moved the integer e and its output before `std::cout << "Enter a number:";` it works normally, but when listed like below only its input works, and the console closes itself.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int raisemath()
{
    std::cout << "Enter an integer: "; // ask user for an integer
    int a; // allocate a variable to hold the user input
    std::cin >> a; // get user input from console and store in variable a
    return a; // return this value to the function's caller (main)
}
int main()
{
    int number;
    std::cout << "Enter a number:";
    std::cin >> number;
    std::cout << "You entered " << number << std::endl;
    int e = raisemath();    
    std::cout << e << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I want to know why?

Comment: The code you show should not even build, much less run. Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, ***Complete*** and ***Verifiable*** Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: And once you got the program to build properly without error (or warnings!) then I recommend that you [learn how to *debug* your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Finding the minimal code that can reproduce your "error" is in itself a good way to solve it. Also using VS2010 make it difficult to have people testing your code in the same environment as you(though the problem is obvious in this case). Try later versions in future.

Answer (score 1):

After the last `std::cout` there is nothing stopping the console from closing.
When you change the `std::cout`'s position there is an input-statement coming after it. So the console waits for the input to continue with the execution.

Preventing the console from closing can be easily achieved by adding a breakpoint at the last return statement or a blank input before the return statement.

You might also want to check your debugger settings to see if the "Automatically close the console when debugging stops" is checked or not. (It's in Tools>Options>Debugging)